# Can nodejs serve android and ios

Tags: android, ios, node.js

I want to build a two player game for android. I was wondering if I can use nodejs as a web server. Can nodejs be used to serve android clients ? How data will be pushed using nodejs to an android client ?
Can it be used to serve iOS client ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you using [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/).

And then use [Socket.IO-Client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) for Java for the android.

Comment: For future reference, a list of available clients: https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, check the [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) page for a quick example.
2. Yes
3. Possibly look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) for handling your communication.